# Where to put Carbon::setLocale() in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, php-carbon

I can't find out where the Carbon localization config should be stated, to be used globally.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
```

Where?

Comment: I'd say in a service providers boot() method; you could use the standard [AppServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php#L16).

Comment: At first there is where I put it, boot() at AppServiceProvider (and it works), but, well, it is not a service, so it doesn't seem right

Comment: Service providers are not solely meant for providing services, but for general application bootstrapping. I'd say that setting the locale on Carbon definitely falls under that category.

Comment: Alternatively you can create a `LocaleServiceProvider` and put it in the boot method there. Though nothing is wrong with using the `AppServiceProvider` for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `AppServiceProvider.php` and add it to the `boot` method

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *    
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
    }
}
```

Comment: At first there is where I put it (and it works), but, well, it is not a service, so it doesn't seem right

Comment: @mikro I know it's a bit late, but I put it to RouteServiceProvider

Answer (score 0):

I found out that to set the locale for **Carbon** in the **App Service Providers**  I need to use a **View composer**.  Otherwise it was not possible to make the
 locale available for my **directives**.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *    
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
       View::composer('*', function ($view) {

            $locale = App::getLocale();

            \Carbon\Carbon::setUtf8(true);
            \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale($locale);
        });
    }
}
```

Here [some more details](https://vegibit.com/what-is-a-view-composer-in-laravel/) about View Composer.